# When I clone/pull git project files get -rw-r--r-- permission. How to avoid read-only access r-- to everyone on the machine in git projects?

Tags: git, permissions, umask

I have reviewed cloned git projects and found that files have `-rw-r--r--` permissions. It means any user on the system can read project files. Of course, it depends on folder permissions, but on some systems `nobody` and all other users can read projects.

Any suggestions if there is a fix for this issue? Why it happens?

For example this works:

```
sudo -u nobody cat /projects/project1/file1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fix this issue"? Because so far everything looks like Git is behaving as intended and there is nothing to fix.

Comment: In a multi-user systems, the aim would be not to give read-only access to users, basically giving permission 0 to everyone. That is the natural need. GIT doesn't track permissions, but this is a default which I'm looking to change, if it's possible.

Comment: This is not Git-specific. Git heeds the umask. Set it to 027, otherwise all tools will give read permission to files that they create, not just Git.

Comment: Ok, `touch file` confirms that any process follows same approach. So I assume an option is to add `umask 027` to `~/.bashrc` (in Linux, usually) to improve security for this user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not *broken* and there is nothing here to fix: this is how permissions are supposed to work on Unix/Linux systems.

Programs, including Git, generally create new files with mode `0666` (`rw-rw-rw-`) unless they're meant to be executable; if they *are* meant to be executable, they create the new files with mode `0777` (`rwxrwxrwx`).  For directories, which must be executable for processes to `chdir` into them or otherwise operate within them, programs call the `mkdir` system call with permissions `0777` (`rwxrwxrwx`).

Files don't actually get created with these permissions *unless* the current process has its `umask` set to `0`.  The umask, which is per-process and inherited in the same fashion as the current working directory, is a mask of bits that the operating system should *clear* before actually creating a new file or directory.  The default umask for a typical user in a typical setup is `022`: this takes away `----w--w-` permissions, so that newly created directories wind up having mode `0755` (`rwxr-xr-x`) and newly created non-executable files have mode `0644` (`rw-r--r--`).

Setting the umask to `077` takes away `---rwxrwx`, so that newly created directories have mode `0700` or `rwx------` and newly created non-executable files have mode `0600` or `rw-------`.  Newly created executable files have mode `0700` or `rwx------` since the process that called for their creation supplied `0777` as the mode, and `0777` masked with `~077` is `0700`.

Git uses these same conventions on Unix and Unix-like systems.  This isn't a Git thing, it's an OS thing.  Note that this simple, easily-understood scheme does not work with complicated things like Access Control Lists (ACLs).  Some use this to argue that the complicated things should not *exist* (and [there is something to that argument](https://www.oilshell.org/blog/2021/08/history-trivia.html)).  The idea of "other" access to files in the first place perhaps should have been removed, since "group"—if groups could be arbitrarily created as needed—would cover such uses.